# BeautifulSoup and Reuters metrics

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a new Python programmer and was trying do scrape some key metrics on Reuters but can't do it properly.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/key-metrics'

page = requests.get(url)

if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
  bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

  list_all_keys = bs.findAll('tr', class_='data')

  key_name = bs.find('th', class_='MarketsTable-label-_JI6s').find('div', class_='TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__gray___1V4fk TextLabel__regular___2X0ym MarketsTable-label-_JI6s')

  for key in key_name:
    beta = key.find('Beta')
    print(beta)
```

Beta is the metric I want. Gives me "-1" as answer. I want the value in 'span' related to the name.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a bit your instructions, I tried to simplify the class request and used `.text` that allows you to extrapolate the text inside. 
I have used the assumption that th and td are the only ones in the row like in the url you asked for (to delete the class selection).

Note: I've used a for, you may use a filter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/key-metrics'

page = requests.get(url)

if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
  bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

  list_all_keys = bs.findAll('tr', class_='data')

  for key in list_all_keys:
    title = key.find("th").text
    if title == "Beta":
      print(key.find("td").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you can do it. 1) You can find the element with  string `"Beta"` in the html, then grab the next `<td>` element. 2) Use pandas' `read_html()` to get the table, then query/pull out what you specifically want from the table. or 3) **I prefer this option as it gets you the raw, un-rendered data:** just get the json response from the API. All solutions are below:

**Solution 1:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/key-metrics'
page = requests.get(url)

if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
  bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

  beta = bs('th',text=re.compile(r'Beta'))[0].find_next('td').text
  print (beta)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/AAPL.OQ/key-metrics'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print (df[df[0] == 'Beta'].iloc[0,1])
```

**Solution 3:**

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AAPL.OQ'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print (jsonData['market_data']['beta'])


df = json_normalize(jsonData['market_data'])
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

# Or to excel file
#df.to_excel('file.xls', index=False)
```

**Output: in order of the solution provided:**

```
1.14
1.13
1.13326
```

**To get the JSON response:**

If you go to `Inspect` the page, and look at the panel on the right. Go to `Network` -> `XHR`. Look through the requests on the left and see if the data you are after in there (might need to reload the page, then you'll need to click around to find it.)

[image]

If you find it, go to `Headers` to get the `Request URL` that you'll use to get that response.

Once you have the response, to convert to a table and output to excel, see the code for Solution 3.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If I may ask (I've been searching for it but I just don't know how to, I guess): how to grab that data from json response and append it to excel?

Comment: good question. I won't be able to answer now, but will add that on to the solution here when I get a chance.